# How to return results for incomplete strings on Nokia Here Maps API?

Tags: here-api

I'm building an application that relies on Here Maps Geocoder API to fetch results based on partial/incomplete strings, in order to give autocomplete suggestions to the user as they start typing something in the search box.

Acording to their documentation, the street field in the query doesnt need to be an exact one, so I expect if i type half the name of the street i would get suggestions for it.

#### Example street name: `Zhibek-Zholy, Almaty, Kazakhstan`:

**With partial street name `Zhib`, INCLUDING city name:**

It gives no results.

```
http://geocoder.cit.api.here.com/6.2/geocode.json?prox=43.260204,76.914597,30000&searchtext=Zhib, Almaty&country=KAZ&app_id=MY_APP_ID&app_code=MY_APP_CODE&gen=8&maxresult=100&language=en
```

**With partial street name `Zhib`, EXCLUDING city name:**

It gives no results.

```
http://geocoder.cit.api.here.com/6.2/geocode.json?prox=43.260204,76.914597,30000&searchtext=Zhib&country=KAZ&app_id=MY_APP_ID&app_code=MY_APP_CODE&gen=8&maxresult=100&language=en
```

**With full street name `Zhibek-Zholy`, including city name:**

It gives me the address.

```
http://geocoder.cit.api.here.com/6.2/geocode.json?prox=43.260204,76.914597,30000&searchtext=Zhibek-Zholy, Almaty&country=KAZ&app_id=MY_APP_ID&app_code=MY_APP_CODE&gen=8&maxresult=100&language=en
```

---

#### Expected behavior:

So, for an autocomplete feature, i should be able to fetch results on a partial match, but this does not seem to be the case with the API.

Anybody has been through the same problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The HERE Geocoder API doesn't offer an autocomplete feature. We have a separate API in BETA for this. Happy to provide you access to this in return for feedback how you like it.
Philip (PM for HERE Geocoder)

[img taken from demo tool](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V6L0t.png)