# One-word-of-the-street-name matching on Nokia HERE API

Tags: here-api

Although similar but not exactly the same problem as [How to return results for incomplete strings on Nokia Here Maps API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31323709/how-to-return-results-for-incomplete-strings-on-nokia-here-maps-api) because I am not doing incomplete strings but rather a complete word but not the whole street address. Specifically, in Barcelona, if I search for the word **Fortuny, 3** it finds **Carrer de Fortuna** but I search for **Pintor Fortuny, 3** then it correctly finds me **Carrer del Pintor Fortuny**

Is there a way for the API to return me **Pintor Fortuny, 3** if my search keyword is **Fortuny**? Or at least give them both so that the user can choose?

Answer (score 0):

In this case your request a complete string but still a minor part of the complete street name. This is not enough information for the Geocoder to find the street which you are looking for.

During the string comparison for 'Fortuny' the shorter street name 'Carrer Fortuny' matches better than 'Carrer del Pintor Fortuny'. You need to provide minimum  'Pintor Fortunity' for a better match.

Comment: Hi Vanessa, the lone street address found was **Carrer Fortuna** (ending in 'a') but by search word was **Fortuny** (ending in 'y') so it seems it chose to auto-correct it as suppose to matching it first with **Carrer del Pintor Fortuny**